# MikTeX cannot be installed

Tags: miktex, installing

I encountered the following problem when I tried to install MiKTeX (64bit edition) on my Windows 7 installation. 
[image]

Could somebody help me out for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the system properties Start Button>Computer>System Properties, See system type. I suspect you are using 32-bit operating system and the MikTex you are installing is for 64-bit operating system
Click https://miktex.org/download and select Basic Installer 32-bit

Comment: The system type is 64-bit operating system. I have checked it.